# How to unstack only the list inside a list of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Hi I'm struggling to unstack this nested list in pandas. Can anyone please help?

This is the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,2], "b" : [['a','b',['c','d']],['a',['b','c']]]})
```

I need to have redundant rows by unstacking only the list inside the list not the whole list.

Output dataframe should be like

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,1,2,2], "b" : [['a','b','c'],['a','b','d'],['a','b'],['a','c']]})
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
from itertools import product

out = (df
  .assign(b=[list(map(list, product(*(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]
                                      for x in l))))
             for l in df['b']])
  .explode('b')
 )
```

Output:

```
   a          b
0  1  [a, b, c]
0  1  [a, b, d]
1  2     [a, b]
1  2     [a, c]
```

Other example:

```
   a                                       b
0  1                         [Burger, Fries]
0  1                         [Burger, Steak]
0  1                       [Burger, Chicken]
0  1                         [Burger, Salad]
1  2                 [Fries, Chicken, Steak]
1  2                   [Fries, Salad, Steak]
1  2                  [Fries, Burger, Steak]
2  3  [Burger, Chicken, Fries, Salad, Steak]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the inner list is always the last element, you could expand the list column and then explode:

```
df[["a"]].join(df.b.apply(lambda x: list(x[:-1] + [last_el] for last_el in x[-1])).explode())
```

Prior to `explode`, this looks as follows:

```
   a                       b
0  1  [[a, b, c], [a, b, d]]
1  2        [[a, b], [a, c]]
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what if the list is not in the last? Lets assume its in the first index position and there's another element in the second index.

Answer (score 0):

You could process your DataFrame series with something that unpacks your list objects, like:

```
def to_1D(series):
    return pd.Series([x for _list in series for x in _list])
```

Have a look at this
[Dealing with List Values in Pandas Dataframes](https://towardsdatascience.com/dealing-with-list-values-in-pandas-dataframes-a177e534f173)

Of course, as mentioned in the followups to your question, this could vary if you need this processing to be flexible to different depth of the nested lists.